# Create Text Document (Python)

Tags: python, text, save

Lets say I want to create a document out of user-inputted code, called `spam.txt`. Assuming I have the user input, say:

```
input("Is Python Good? ")
```

How can I save the text, that the user inputted, to a text file, and can one do this?

Comment: This is covered by the Python tutorial: http://docs.python.org/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files. I recommend finishing that, or another such document, before taking to SO.

Comment: "...  and can one do this?" :-)

Comment: This helped me.  Not sure why this was closed.

Comment: I don't see any localization in this question. It seems this is likely a duplicate but not a localization.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

```
f = open('file.txt','w')
a = input('is python good?')
f.write('answer:'+str(a))
f.close()
```

Easy no? :)

Comment: The `str(a)` seems to make things too complex.  Could you pick one version of Python (3.x or 2.x) and use either `input` or `raw_input` to make this simpler?

Comment: In which sense too complex? str(value) is a standard command of python, if you use str() on a string it doesn't hurts, if you use it on numbers it converts them to strings making this snippet working. This code works both on version 2.7 and 3.x, where is the problem?

Comment: If you use `raw_input` you don't need `str` at all.  That would be simpler.  If you choose to claim this is Python 3, and use `input`, you don't need `str` at all.  That would be simpler.

Comment: Thanks, it's more clear now :-)

Answer (score 18):

```
with open('spam.txt', 'a') as f:
    f.write(string_output)
```