# how to create an ".scr" or ".txt" output file from python result

Tags: python, file, text

Firstly, I have to tell you that I'm an absolute noob at python and 
started using it hoping to be able to create small executable files for
basic engineering tasks. For example, the below code calculates the tracing
coordinates for a progressive curve for railways:

```
l=int(input('l='))
r=int(input('r='))
for x in range(0,l+1,2):
    y=round(((x**3)/(6*l*r)),4)
for x in range(0,l+1,2):
    grafic=print(x,",",round(((x**3)/(6*l*r)),4),sep='')
```

with the output, for given variables values:

```
l=42
r=195
0,0.0
2,0.0002
4,0.0013
6,0.0044
8,0.0104
10,0.0204
12,0.0352
14,0.0558
16,0.0834
18,0.1187
20,0.1628
22,0.2167
24,0.2813
26,0.3577
28,0.4467
30,0.5495
32,0.6668
34,0.7998
36,0.9495
38,1.1166
40,1.3024
42,1.5077
```

I'm trying to create a ".scr" or ".txt" file from this result which must be:

```
pline
0,0.0
2,0.0002
4,0.0013
6,0.0044
8,0.0104
10,0.0204
12,0.0352
14,0.0558
16,0.0834
18,0.1187
20,0.1628
22,0.2167
24,0.2813
26,0.3577
28,0.4467
30,0.5495
32,0.6668
34,0.7998
36,0.9495
38,1.1166
40,1.3024
42,1.5077
```

The ideea is to creat a script file which can be imported in ACAD for example,
the output beeing that it traces a 2D polyline.
Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: `open` a file and `write` to it.

Comment: Unrelated to the question, but `print` returns `None`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Create Text Document (Python)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9284507/create-text-document-python)

Comment: Thanks! I tried:f=open('trasare.txt','w')
f.write(str(grafic))
f.close()  it creates a file which contains just "None"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to redirect 'print' output to a file using python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7152762/how-to-redirect-print-output-to-a-file-using-python)

Answer (score 0):

You can create a file with the built-in [open](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open) function from Python:

```
with open('output.txt', 'w') as outfile:
    outfile.write("pline\n")
    l = int(input('l='))
    r = int(input('r='))
    for x in range(0, l + 1, 2):
        y = round(((x ** 3) / (6 * l * r)), 4)
    for x in range(0, l + 1, 2):
        outfile.write("{},{}\n".format(x, round(((x ** 3) / (6 * l * r)), 4)))
```

**Output**

```
pline
0,0.0
2,0.0002
4,0.0013
6,0.0044
8,0.0104
10,0.0204
12,0.0352
14,0.0558
16,0.0834
18,0.1187
20,0.1628
22,0.2167
24,0.2813
26,0.3577
28,0.4467
30,0.5495
32,0.6668
34,0.7998
36,0.9495
38,1.1166
40,1.3024
42,1.5077
```

The function `outfile.write` writes the text to the file, in the example above `outfile`. To write a line you must append the newline character `\n` at the end of each string you write.

Comment: Great! Glad I could help

Answer (score 0):

you can use `write`

1. open your text file as textfile
2. use \n for new line
3. use `textfile.write`